# how to read output of var_export into a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, import

the output is like below restored in a output.txt file:

```
array (
  'IMType' => '1',
  'Email' => 'test@gmail.com',
  'SignupName' => 'test11',
  'Password' => '11111',
  'Encrypted' => '',
  'Confirm' => '11111',
  'OldPassword' => '',
  'Name' => 'test',
  'SignupProvinceText' => 'province',
  'SignupCity' => 'cityname',
  'Street' => 'street x.y',
  'SignupIndustry' => 'IT',
  'SignupCompany' => 'jobirn',
  'SignupJt' => 'engineer',
  'CellPhoneNum' => '',
  'linked_in' => '',
)
```

it's in fact output of `var_export(my_variable,true)`,but how to read it into a variable again?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

like this:

```
$dumpStr = var_export($var,true);
eval('$somevar = ' . $dumpStr . ';');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: Be *very* careful with eval, and only use it if you are 100% completely sure that the user can't inject any code.

Comment: agreed about the danger there. hence my comment to Zilupe's answer.

Comment: Also, it should be eval('$somevar = ' . $dumpStr); as + is only used for addition. (If I remember correctly.)

Comment: hahah, quite right. That's what I get for working on javascript all day

Comment: This does not work if you are not currently in the global namespace and you are trying import an object because PHP will expect all the class names to be in the current namespace.

Comment: Sometimes you should add `;` for evaluating variable. 
For example: 
`eval( '$somevar = '. $dumpStr .';' );`

Comment: i think this solution is not good. eval is too dangerous, look at my response in bottom of this page.

Comment: Security issues aside, this solution doesn't even work in many cases. `var_export` generates a lot of calls to the `__set_state` method, and if even a single class doesn't have this method implemented, the evaluation will fail.

Answer (score 20):

Perhaps you want to serialize object and then unserialize?
http://php.net/serialize

Comment: the data structure is restored in a file.can it be directly imported without serialization?

Comment: yes, this is probably what he wants. And is safer than using eval

Comment: @Shore what do you mean by "directly imported without serialization"? Serialization is the process of storing an object. Unserialization is the restoration of the stored object. You can restore objects serialized with anything you wish, but they should follow the format (consult PHP.net)

Comment: @Jonathan, it is NOT safer than eval. Quote from the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php): **Warning** Do not pass untrusted user input to unserialize(). Unserialization can result in code being loaded and executed due to object instantiation and autoloading, and a malicious user may be able to exploit this. Use a safe, standard data interchange format such as JSON (via json_decode() and json_encode()) if you need to pass serialized data to the user.

Answer (score 11):

its very simple , you must save it as php file not txt and then

just include it inside a variable :)

like this:

```
    file_put_contents( '/some/file/data.php', 
                       '<?php return '.var_export( $data_array, true ).";\n" );
```

when you need to access it just do this :

```
$data = include '/some/file/data.php'
```

Comment: includes returns 1 on success and FALSE on failure. Using it that way will not result in the contents of data.php being assigned to $data.

Comment: @AlexanderGarden you are wrong. when you are returning result inside php file you can get value with include inside another variable like what i did for $data. look at 5# example of this link from php.net -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 2):

This technique is good for data cache:

```php
<?php
// reading data from DB or an API webservice etc.
$arrName = array();    
$arrName = call_procedure_here();

$strFileContent = '<?php' . PHP_EOL . '$arrName = ' . var_export($arrName,true) . ';' . PHP_EOL . '?>';
file_put_contents('cache_folder/arrayfilename.php', $strFileContent);

// later... from another process
include 'cache_folder/arrayfilename.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a basic `var_export` parser, without eval: [VarExportParser.php](https://github.com/klesun-misc/dev_data/blob/master/common/php/VarExportParser.php)

Usage:

```
require_once('VarExportParser.php');
$parsed = VarExportParser::parse("array ('IMType' => '1', 'Email' => 'test@gmail.com')");
print(json_encode($parsed).PHP_EOL);
```

Outputs:

```
{"IMType":"1","Email":"test@gmail.com"}
```

You can try js version of it here: [text_transform.html](https://klesun-misc.github.io/dev_data/text_transform.html#dataset=varExportExample) (the *var_export to json* button)