# How to convert plaintext to array?

Tags: php

How can i convert string from txt file to array?

**Text.txt**

```
"1" => "Text1",
"2" => "Text2",
"3" => "Text3",
"4" => "Text4",
```

**index.php**

```
$a = file_get_contents('Text.txt');
explode(',', $a); ???
```

I wanna see a pair of $key => $value. Is it possible?

Comment: Where and why do you save your text in a text file like this?! Save it in a portable  format like JSON

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2662268/3933332

Comment: it's only of curiosity

Comment: I think then the answer is don't do it?! question answered ?