# Hardcode array for reuse in php file?

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know if this is even called "hardcoding", but I would like to build an array (for example from a mysqli_fetch_assoc query) and output it for reuse in a config.php file.

So this output from mysql would be:

```
[structure] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [structureid] => 23
                [active] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [structureid] => 25
                [active] => 1
            )
```

And it would be stored like this in a config.php file:

```
$structure[0]['structureid'] = 23;
$structure[0]['active'] = 1;
$structure[1]['structureid'] = 25;
$structure[1]['active'] = 1;
```

Is there an easy and quick way to accomplish this?

As someone has pointed out, I could resolve this with using a json file - which I'm already doing - but I wanted to check if there would be another (quick) way of doing it as described above.

Comment: why you don't use `foreach` loop?

Comment: as its stored in the db, why not just querry that when required?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I store an array in a file to access as an array later with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662268/how-do-i-store-an-array-in-a-file-to-access-as-an-array-later-with-php)

Comment: @Dagon: for this specific case it needs to be exported to run without a database - I have a solution through json, but I wanted to know if there was a another way **without** going through a json file.

Comment: U can store in cookies if its static

Comment: quick and dirty write the serialized version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [var_export()](http://php.net/var_export), to create a readable (and in-code-reusable) array, that you can then put in a config file:

```
$reusableCode = var_export($yourArray, true);
```

Or to just output it:

```
var_export($yourArray);
```

You can put that in a config file with an return, like this:

```
return array(
    'your' => 'values'
);
```

and then [require](http://php.net/require) it from your code:

```
$configData = require('yourConfigFileWithTheArray.php');
```

Comment: I wish this would work - since it would be the best answer I found, but trying to do it this way, and then using get_defined_vars() to display them - doesn't work. Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: @Taapo Well, how exactly are you including it and did you remember to add the `return` in the file? Is error reporting on?

Comment: I was wrong. I forgot to create a variable to read the array into. It works now - very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I Initially misread your question,

So you want to store `mysql` resource to a file?

You mentionned that you are using `JSON` is to solve this.

This is a good way to do it, the other way would be to serialize/deserialize the object than save them to a file. `JSON` solution is simple human readable.

Example:

```
$data = serialize($rows);
file_put_contents('data.txt', $data);

$data = file_get_contents('data.txt');
$rows = unserialize($data);
```

But you won't be able to read the output of the serialization.