# Php router script which uses existing htaccess

Tags: php

I need a PHP router script, which uses an existing htaccess file with many redirects like:

```
Redirect 302 /some.ts http://targeturl/target.ts
```

I already searched through a lot of code examples but couldn't find a fitting one and I'm an absolute PHP beginner. It should be a router for the PHP Dev Server.

Would be nice if someone could give me an example here. Thanks!

**Update**

I have now a first script try (with some help of AI):

```
<?php

// Get the requested URI
$requestURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$filePath = __DIR__ . $requestURI;

/**
 * Retrieves the redirect rules from the .htaccess file
 *
 * @return array
 */
function getHtaccessRedirectRules()
{
    // Get the contents of the .htaccess file
    $htaccessContent = file_get_contents('/www/.htaccess');

    // Extract the redirect rules using a regular expression
    $pattern = '/Redirect 302\s+(?P<expr>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<file>[^\s]+)/';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $htaccessContent, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    // Build an array of redirect rules
    $redirectRules = [];
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $oldPage = str_replace('"', '', $match[1]);
        $newPage = str_replace('"', '', $match[2]);
        $redirectRules[$oldPage] = $newPage;
    }
    
    return $redirectRules;
}

// Check if the requested file exists
if (file_exists($filePath) && !is_dir($filePath)) {
    // Serve the file directly
    return false;
}

// Retrieve the redirect rules from the .htaccess file
$redirectRules = getHtaccessRedirectRules();

// Check if the requested URI matches any redirect rules
foreach ($redirectRules as $oldPage => $newPage) {
    if ($requestURI === $oldPage) {
        // Redirect to the new page
        header("Location: $newPage", true, 302);
        exit;
    }
}

// If no redirect rule matches, serve a 404 page
http_response_code(404);
echo '404 Page Not Found';

?>
```

It's still not working but i checked the regular expression with:
https://www.phpliveregex.com/#tab-preg-match

The result looks ok for me.
At the moment i only get "Accepted" and "Closing" Messages out of the PHP Dev Server.

Maybe somebody else sees some issue(s).

Thanks!

Comment: Big Thanks @hakre! I found the isssue with the errorlog() function in the Array Build Section where the Matches where not numbered correctly. $oldPage is $match[1] and $newPage is $match[2] :-)

Comment: Now as the script works as desired maybe somebody can give me some performance optimization tip to get faster redirects as the script needs to go through a large htaccess file, which for sure takes some seconds.

Comment: Yeah thanks for these great tips! I first need to think about how can achieve the array cache because the htaccess will be updated on a regular schedule too 

Comment: Great the PHP Array works fine and very fast! Thanks again! :-)

Comment: I build the PHP Array now directly through my script which generated the htaccess before for Apache so my router script is much shorter at the end ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this one you already found, the matching group numbers of the regular expression pattern were wrong:

```php
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $oldPage = str_replace('"', '', $match[2]);
        $newPage = str_replace('"', '', $match[3]);
        $redirectRules[$oldPage] = $newPage;
    }
```

The need to be `1` and `2` respectively:

```php
$pattern = '/Redirect 302\s+(?P<expr>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<file>[^\s]+)/';
#           |               `-----(1)------´   `------(2)-----´|
#           `-------------------------(0)----------------------´
```

Another improvement for the regular expression pattern with *preg_match()* in your case is to drop the naming of the matching groups as you're not using them:

```php
$pattern = '/Redirect 302\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)/';
#           |               `-(1)--´   `-(2)--´|
#           `---------------(0)----------------´
```

This is a little optimization as well, as PHP will use less memory, the `$matches` array then has less items and can safe the memory of two string keys per each match item. Internally this has also the benefit that PHP can optimize such arrays as they are a *list* (*[array_is_list()](https://php.net/array_is_list)*), that means starting with integer key `0` and all following keys are consecutive integers. PHP then can optimize (memory and speed).

---

```php
        $oldPage = str_replace('"', '', $match[1]);
        $newPage = str_replace('"', '', $match[2]);
        $redirectRules[$oldPage] = $newPage;
```

This are two str_replace() calls made per each $match that are doing the same search and replace, only the subject is different.

str_replace() can operate on an array of subjects. So the two function calls can be replaced with one:

```php
        [$oldPage,  $newPage ] = str_replace('"', '', [$match[1], $match[2]]);
        $redirectRules[$oldPage] = $newPage;
```

This is normally an optimization in PHP as function calls are *relatively* expensive while array creation and destructing is not. But this is on a level you would normally need to run the metrics with your own data and then compare different implementations to each other. So the benefit could not be speed here, but having the pairing better aligned, so more straight forward code that is easier to maintain.

---

Now then some real optimization trick in PHP (given you don't have an enormous amount of key-collisions):

Looking up the request URI for a potential redirect. In the original code we have a *foreach* loop (already pretty fast in php) to compare if the array *key* matches the request URI:

```php
// Check if the requested URI matches any redirect rules
foreach ($redirectRules as $oldPage => $newPage) {
    if ($requestURI === $oldPage) {
        // Redirect to the new page
        header("Location: $newPage", true, 302);
        exit;
    }
}
```

As this is basically the lookup of the *key* in the array (*$redirectRules*), PHP is faster doing so by directly accessing/querying the item in the array. As PHP internally uses a hash-map for the array keys if there are string keys involved – this is why arrays that are a list can be optimized, no expensive string hashing is required for them, all keys are consecutive integers starting with 0 – directly testing for the array item by its key to test for existence is (most often) faster than looping over the array. the loop is very fast when the first entry matches, but the loop can not benefit from PHPs internal array hashmap, which is much more effective to find the item in the map regardless if it is first or last.

This was much explanation, the key part is that in PHP we can use arrays as maps (string keys, associative array), and the lookup of the key then is an optimization when it can replace a loop.

```php
$newPage = $redirectRules[$requestURI] ?? null
```

Variable $newPage is only set if a redirect rule for the request uri exist.

As there are two possible outcomes – array has a member for that key *or* not – we provide the value for the case the key test fails. This works with the *null-coalescing operator* ("??"). An undefined array entry in PHP emits a warning unless the *??* operator is in use to handle the case and provide a value to use instead.

Here we use the `null` value which means that there is a value but its not a value. Hence it pretty much expresses what we're looking for: the not-found entry.

```php
// Check if the requested URI matches any redirect rules
if ($newPage = $redirectRules[$requestURI] ?? null) {
    // Redirect to the new page
    header("Location: $newPage", true, 302);
    exit;
}
```

This way of writing code is that common in PHP that I have the tendency to just quench it within if-clauses already, that is there *is* a variable assignment in the if-clause. It depends on context whether that is expected or not, so the assignment could be done before the if and the if then operating on the variable only, perhaps even make it clear that we are looking for a variable that is not empty:

```php
// Check if the requested URI matches any redirect rules
$newPage = $redirectRules[$requestURI] ?? null;
if (!empty($newPage)) {
    // Redirect to the new page
    header("Location: $newPage", true, 302);
    exit;
}
```

---

*Further:* An example of how to store a PHP array on disk an load it back later is here: [*Answer to:* How do I store an array in a file to access as an array later with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55421531/367456)