# String to array conversion if string has content like an array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have something like this:

```
array('fields' => array(
             0 => array('name'  => 'family_name', 
                        'label' => 'Family Names'),
                  array('name'  => given_names', 
                        'label' => 'Given Names'),
                  array('name'  => 'additional_names',
                        'label' => 'Additional Names'),
                  array('name'  => 'honorific_prefixes', 
                        'label' => 'Honorific Prefixes'),
                  array('name'  => honorific_suffixes', 
                        'label' => 'Honorific Suffixes')
                       )
                    )
```

in a variable as string. The whole thing is in one database field. If I output the variable, it is a string.
I would have an array with the content as subarrays. How do I convert this value into an array?

I searched with google, but I found explode and split and so on, but I think I miss the key word to find any solution.

Thank you for any help in this case.

Comment: The simplest way to be use `eval` for this, however you must be sure there is no risk of evil injection

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to read output of var\_export into a variable in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933506/how-to-read-output-of-var-export-into-a-variable-in-php)

Comment: Why do you store the data in such a way in your database? you could use JSON, e.g., for easier conversions.

Comment: Store result of `json_encode`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using eval(), https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

```
eval("\$array = $string;");
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string is not built correctly to put it into the eval function. Two strings inside don't have the preceding quote and that will lead to a parse error. But you can correct it with:

```
$string = str_replace("=> given_names'", "=> 'given_names'", $string);
$string = str_replace("=> honorific_suffixes'", "=> 'honorific_suffixes'", $string);
```

After that you can use the answer of shapeshifter (please mark his answer as the correct one):

```
eval("\$array = $string;");
var_dump($array);
```

---

If you just look for a method to save and restore your arrays you could also use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/function.serialize.php) / [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/function.unserialize.php).